# pip install tensorflow throw error when it try to install related packeg:futures

Tags: python, tensorflow

Environment: python 3.6.2

When I try to install `tensorflow-gpu` with this command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

It throws an error message when it tries to install related `packeg:futures`

> Unknown requires Python '>=2.6, <3' but the running Python is 3.6.2.

But `futures` is `python2` only package.

How can I handle it?

[image: error img]

Answer (score 2):

I find the issue in github :

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16478

it should install futures first:

pip3 install futures==3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source from pypi `futures-3.2.0.tar.gz` and install.